# Get query Output from database

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the query output from oracle database. Not only result, output.

Example, When i execute the following query;

```
Create table test ( id varchar2(20);
```

I want to get '`Table Created.'` output. I know that oracle  and sql server have default outputs like this.

I use below code to get execute sqls and works fine, it creates table however it doesn't return any output;

```
            string oradb = GlobalCs.oraCon;
            odagetSQL = new OracleDataAdapter(createTableSQL, oradb);
            DataTable dtSQL = new DataTable();
            odagetSQL.Fill(dtSQL);
            ugSQLResult.DataSource = dtSQL;
```

I wonder that how can i get query output as i stated ?

Comment: no error(exception) = create success

Comment: The OracleConnection has an InfoMessage event. Not tried but perhaps you could get your info from that event

Comment: "I know that oracle and sql server have default outputs like this." Do they? Different SQL client programs say different things in my experience. If I run `Create TABLE test ( id varchar(20));` in MS SQL Server via SSMS it says "Command(s) completed successfully.". If I run the same statement, against the same database, using Atlantis SQL Everywhere (for example) it says "Start of batch 1 at line 1
--------------------------

End of batch 1, completed in 0.046 seconds." and some more guff. I think the GUI generates this specifically, not the DB engine.

Comment: @Steve tried that but it throws something else, not what i want.

Comment: if it throws then it means something failed....

Comment: @ADyson well, i create this table using 3 or more 3rd party application and all of them shows same output.

Comment: @Steve i mean, it says about connection not about query output.

Comment: maybe they followed some standard text, or maybe not, I couldn't say. It doesn't guarantee that the DB engine produced the text. BTW using a DataAdapter to run a DDL statement is a bit weird and unnecessary, since it returns no resultset. You can use a simple command object, I think.

Comment: that's a different problem then. Your question is about to get that create success message. So if your create statement ran without exception then you can just assume that message was print out

Comment: dont know about oracle but sql-server returns nothing if a create table succeeded. When a select/update/insert/delete succeeded you can ask the rows affected from sql-server, but you need to do that yourself it will not return it by default. I guess oracle is doing something similar